# how do I have an url in the below format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am able to generate a url and associated web page with the help of the `rails generate controller static_pages about`. So the url would be something like this `www.bla.com/static_pages/about'. Now I want to generate this url`bla.com/help` without the use of generate,

I added a route in routes.rb like this
`get 'help'`

Then I added an action in application_controller.rb like this 
`def hello
   render text: "Hello"
 end`

Then when started the server, I get the following error

```
Exiting
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:275:in `check_part': Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes. (ArgumentError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:255:in `check_controller_and_action'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:178:in `normalize_options!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:100:in `initialize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:78:in `new'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:78:in `build'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1559:in `add_route'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1536:in `decomposed_match'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1517:in `block in match'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1507:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1507:in `match'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:689:in `map_method'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:650:in `get'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/config/routes.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:410:in `draw'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/config.ru:3:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/config.ru:in `new'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/bin/rails:8:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/bin/spring:13:in `require'
        from /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your
>   routes. (ArgumentError)

As the error states, you need to specify `controller` and `action` matching to the `route`. The below should work.

```
get "help", to: 'static_pages#about', as: 'help'
                    ^^^^^^    ^^^^
                 controller   action
```

Also, I suggest you to follow these [***Guides***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for clear understanding on how to define the routes.

Comment: I do not have staticpages/help. Nor do I want it, I want it be bla.com/help

Comment: @gates The route will be as you wanted :)

Comment: Final question, so how should the help.html.erb should be inside views/static_pages now?

Comment: @gates As how you wanted to look like :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91306/discussion-between-gates-and-pavan).